# Issue with Checkbox's and API 23

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've a problem with the status of the AppCompatCheckBox and the colors it shows in the box and the api 23 after I update the target platforms to android 9.0 API 28.

If I initialize my checkbox in true, it shows the check correctly [checkbox initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx8BX.png)

But, if I uncheck the box it shows the blank box with the edges of my primary color [check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVZFz.png) It should be gray border, white background.

And when you check, this appears bad [unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0JkP.png) It should be boder and background blue.

I build the checkboxes programatically

```cs
var checkBox = new AppCompatCheckBox(Context));
checkBox.checked = MyObj.Value;
AddView(checkBox);
```

And in my style I define the colors

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarker</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDarker</item>
</style>
```

And I'm using the package nuget Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat version 28.0.0.1 and MvvmCross 6.3.0

This only happens with devices with API 23 and in mode release, in debug works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this question by using device with api 23  in release mode, it just worked normally. Could you share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: I @JessieZhang, thank you for your interest. I was changing things in my project and discovered that when I have disabled the proguard everything works fine. I still do not know what is happening with that. I have a custom configuration file, I'm reviewing it.

Comment: In mi file _proguard.cfg_ I've this: `-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class android.support.** { *; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after several hours, I had to change my *proguard.cfg* file to this:

```
 -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
 -keep class android.support.** { *; }
 -keep class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox { *; }
```

Directly placing my appcompatcheckbox class. It was the only solution I found.