# Xamarin Android AppCompatCheckBox error when link sdk with target 9.0 API 28 running on 6.0 API 23

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an app targeted 8.1 API 27. After targeted to 9.0, I found the CheckBox has a strange behavior:

- On the first click, the box is not checked but the value “checked” has changed
- From the second click on, the check mark and “checked” value are toggled accordingly
- i.e. the check mark is not in sync with the value “checked” since the first click

This error happens **only in the combination** of

- release build with linking SDK assembly (debug mode no problem)
- target 9.0 API 28 (target 8.1 no problem)
- running on 6.0 API 23 (both Genymotion emulator and real device have problem. Tested on 4.4, 7.0, 9.0 no problem)

It can be re-produced with a new Xamarin project – Android App. 
In content_main.axml, replace content with:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
```

In MainActivity.OnCreate, add code to check result

```
        TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        CheckBox cb = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        cb.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                tv.Text = "checked";
            }
            else
            {
                tv.Text = "not checked";
            }
        };
```

Furthermore, when create checkbox in code (in appcomp activity):

- Using AppCompatCheckBox class will have the same error as in xml
- Using CheckBox class has no error

In my app, I fixed the code generated checkbox with “CheckBox” class instead of appcomp. However, I could not find any workaround for xml as it was defined as “CheckBox” already.

It is most likely related to linking (but on API 23 only???) One possible solution is to not linking the AppCompatCheckBox. I tried skip linking classes CheckBox and AppCompatCheckBox using linker configuration file. It does not work (maybe I did it wrong). Then I tried skip linking the whole assemblies of "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" and "Mono.Android" using linker properties. It does not work too.

The checkbox behaves normally only when no linking.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Nick

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this question by the steps you said.It workded just properly.

Comment: Jessie, I add a link to download my test project. I can produce the error on Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S6 Android 6.0 API 23. Please try if the error can be shown on your side. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nick, I'd advise you to provide your error in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android with the part of the ProGuard since this seems like a bug from Xamarin.Android. You need to provide your repository or an example to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,I could reproduce this question by your demo, but I also resolved this question by unchecking the `Enable Proguard` option as follows, here the `ProGuard option`  should have removed the necessary libraries we need.
For more details ,you can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#proguard  .
[image]

Comment: Jessie thank you very much for pointing out that is a Proguard issue (proguard + linking indeed). I just found the same issue was asked a month ago at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783187/issue-with-checkboxs-and-api-23. Following that post, I further narrow down the class to keep in proguard for android.support.graphics.** to resolve it. Thanks.